# Flutter/Dart - I need second screen to show nested section of JSON that matches parameter recieved from first screen

Tags: json, flutter, dart

In my app I have a main screen that has a series of clickable ListTiles listing dangerous snakes (with just a title and image).

These ListTiles will have an onTap() function calling MaterialPageRoute that sends a string type parameter to a second screen that is supposed to load the JSON details for the chosen snake using this parameter. The Parameter is called **taxonString**.

IE:

```
onTap: () {Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SpeciesScreen(taxonString: "mozambiqueSpittingCobra"),),);}
```

I can receive this parameter no problem and display it in in a widget, ie:

```
  Text(widget.taxonString),
```

The problem is - I have a JSON file that lists the details of each snake (nested under 'species' key) and the KEY for each species within the JSON file must match the received **taxonString** string.

My JSON:

```
{"species":
  {
    "mozambiqueSpittingCobra":
      {
        "commonName": "Mozambique Spitting Cobra",
        "latinName": "Naja mossambica",
        "swaziName": "Imfeti",
        "distributionDanger": "The Mozambique spitting cobra is found...",
        "habits": "habits long text.",
        "description": "description long text....",
        "behaviour": "behaviourfirstAid",
        "firstAid": "firstAidfirstAid",
        "biteSymptoms": [array of strings]
      },
    "vineSnake":
    {
      "commonName": "Vine Snake",
      "latinName": "Thelotornis capensis",
      "swaziName": "Indlolo",
      "distributionDanger": "The Vine Snake is found throughout Eswatini...",
        "habits": "habits long text.",
        "description": "description long text....",
        "behaviour": "behaviourfirstAid",
        "firstAid": "firstAidfirstAid",
        "biteSymptoms": [array of strings]
    },
    "snoutedCobra":
    {
      "commonName": "Snouted Cobra",
      "latinName": "Naja annulifera",
      "swaziName": "Imfeti",
      "distributionDanger": "The Snouted cobra is found throughout ....",
        "habits": "habits long text.",
        "description": "description long text....",
        "behaviour": "behaviourfirstAid",
        "firstAid": "firstAidfirstAid",
        "biteSymptoms": [array of strings]
    },
    //Extra JSON removed for brevity...
  }
}
```

The taxonString value, in this case 'mozambiqueSpittingCobra', MUST load ONLY the portion of nested JSON matching the received taxonString parameter to the same KEY in the JSON.

I have spent over a week researching and trying different things mainly here in SO.

I CAN get the correct species to display if I hard code the species KEY into the details page, ie:

```
  factory SpeciesClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SpeciesClass(
      thisTaxon: TaxonClass.fromJson(json['mozambiqueSpittingCobra'])
  );
```

I tried to use a variable that holds the value of the received parameter but no luck, ie:

```
  factory SpeciesClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SpeciesClass(
      thisTaxon: TaxonClass.fromJson(json[widget.taxonString])
  );
```

I was hoping I could use the passed parameter from the first page like a variable, or use a WHERE condition saying something like..

```
 load species fromJason Where species = widget.taxonString
```

I hope I gave enough info.

Please shed some light.

*I am new to Dart/Flutter (and OOP) - but as a web developer I am comfortable with code (Vanilla PHP, Javascript, ASP).
I DO NOT have experience with JSON but I am learning.*

Comment: can you print out `widget.taxonString` and see what is displayed in the console ? 
afterwards if it's the correct result, can you print out `json[widget.taxonString]` and see what is in that ?

Comment: Thank you for you reply Charles.

I have a device attached so I cant seem to print to console. If I remove the device it says "no device found'.

If I run `widget.taxonString` in a Text Widget on the device I get the proper result.

If I try run `json[widget.taxonString]` I get the following error: 

Instance members can't be accessed from a factory constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the keyword `factory` before you function definition

Comment: When I remove the factory keyword the IDE underlines the whole code block in red.